# Global css file won't override component css

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a file global.css in assets folder, file is imported in main.js. Styles from this file works only if i dont have same style applied in component style. For example, in component i have this

```
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

then in global.css

```
h1 {
  font-size: 35px
}
```

this won't work. Is there a way to override component styles with this global.css?

Comment: Why do you want in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `h1 { font-size: 35px !important; }`

Or with classes

For example:

```
.headline-h1 {
  font-size: 35px
}
```

Comment: That is probably a solution but worst too, imagine typing that on hundreds of lines.

Comment: Nope, don't use `!important`. Using a proper adequate solution is probably better than using a nuke and breaking all the rules.

Comment: @EdinOsmic So otherwise you need to use classes for this

Comment: @Hi1mNico classes is a way of dealing with specificity, not the only one tho.

Comment: @kissu He said "imagine typing that on hundreds of lines". Sounds like its about more than one specified headline

Comment: @Hi1mNico there are probably solutions for that. Otherwise, this is a decision making problem and better start refactoring or making a quick script. Still, some details are highly welcome overall.

Comment: @kissu Yeah I think your right. But in lack of details, that was the help I could offer out with my knowledge.

Comment: @Hi1mNico still, do not recommend `!important`. This is rarely a good approach and causes more issues than solves them. Too many people who are not good enough in CSS fallback to this. As [shown here](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/), there are far better approaches which are far less overkill.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for this overview. Pretty helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your style tag within component has **scoped** attribute otherwise it'll override global styles.

Review: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-demo-j87nz0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: OP asks for the opposite actually.

Comment: Generally this kind of style problem cause by scoped scope(un/intentional) in component which prevent global css rules and override it.

Comment: Here, OP wants to "unscope" the styling and use the global styling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) to solve this issue.
Here, it's happening because the global style is applied at first, then component style comes in second, you could inspect that in your devtools and see various declarations applied to your `h1` element.

There are of course advanced possibilities in CSS but writing something more specific

```css
h1.my-cool-class { /* or just .my-cool-class */
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

should be enough here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for answering. I had to deal with some messy css, every component had its own css style for every heading and paragraph(sizes, colors, fonts, etc.). I deleted all of these and put them in global.css file and then changed html elements to be compatible with sizes. That's it.